# What's the meaning of "standing in yourself"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The following are comments made on the effect of social media on people. On person 2's remark, what does *standing in yourself* mean that I bolded?

Person 1:

> Normally I roll my eyes at people who are anti-social media. I’ve made numerous close friends and professional connections through Twitter. I’ve reconnected with old friends on Facebook. Those are good things. But as I kept reading “The Circle” and thinking about Louis C.K.’s comments, I found myself more and more uncomfortable with just how dependent I was...

Person 2:

> *"Normally I roll my eyes at people who are anti-social media".*
>
> I'm one of those people.
>
> It all depends on where you're **standing in yourself**, I suppose. I've meditated at least one hour a day for 25 years. People often comment: "I could never find the time for that." But of course many people spend at least that much time gorging themselves on social media every day.
>
> I tried facebook for one year--family, friends, old high school buddies--all that. In the end I quit... not so much because it was a huge waste of time (which it is) but because it was a huge waste of ME. YOU are more valuable than all that rot. I assure you that once you spend some consistent quality time with yourself you'll come to the same conclusion. You're far more valuable than the Borg!
>
> "Distracting ourselves to death" is not just a clever turn of phrase.

Comment: It doesn't mean anything - it's ungrammatical in the form posted - and it isn't something a native speaker would normally ever say.

Comment: It's not ungrammatical, which we can see if we replace *yourself* with another NP such as *the room*.  It does appear nonsensical to me, but it appears that a few native speakers **do** use the phrase, and presumably they mean something by it.  It looks like it may be an idiomatic loan translation of *[sva](http://spokensanskrit.de/index.php?script=HK&beginning=0+&tinput=%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B5&trans=Translate&direction=AU)[stha](http://spokensanskrit.de/index.php?tinput=stha&script=&direction=SE&link=yes)*, since they mention meditation in the next sentence.

Comment: Take a look at [**this**](http://books.google.com/books?id=9eMN5kmVWvoC&pg=PA46&lpg=PA46&dq=%22standing+in+yourself%22&source=bl&ots=PqfngcnHYC&sig=jxBJOa56x215yIpAf9MdRjJUVDU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=BwxsUvOyOuHbyQHO_YGYCA&ved=0CGkQ6AEwDQ#v=onepage&q=%22standing%20in%20yourself%22&f=false). Google has all the answers! -you just have to know which ones are right.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that the poster is coming from the perspective of a meditator. They likely have some awareness of the inner workings of their mind and can recognize whether they are coming from a reactive place or a detached observer place (or some other self defined space).  These "places" are actually different points of view that exist within each of us.